# Laravel - Join with a table with composite primary key

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel

My problem is to join 2 tables in Laravel framework. One is **dynamic name table** (it's a variable) and second has **composite primary key**. I have to use query builder instead of where(). Please view my following for details:

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `details` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `source_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`brand_id`)
);
```

Now, I need to join 2 these tables, I use this code:

```
<?php $results =  \DB::table('details')
            ->join('links', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('details.source_id', '=',  'links.source_id');
                $join->on('details.brand_id','=', 'links.brand_id');
            })
            ->get();?>
```

It's quite simple to join these table, OK. But my problem is the table name is dynamic.

```
<?php 
$type = Input::get('type', null);
$table = $type . '_details';
$results =  \DB::table($table)
                ->join('links', function($join)
                {
                    // the following code will show errors undefined $table
                    $join->on($table . '.source_id', '=',  'links.source_id');
                    $join->on($table . '.brand_id','=', 'links.brand_id');
                })
                ->get();

?>
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to import variables from the local scope to the anonymous function's scope, this is how:

```
$results =  \DB::table($table)
                ->join('links', function($join) use ($table)
                {
                    $join->on($table . '.source_id', '=',  'links.source_id');
                    $join->on($table . '.brand_id','=', 'links.brand_id');
                })
                ->get();
```

Notice the line:

```
->join('links', function($join) use ($table)
```

Problem is the anonymous function doesn't know about the variable `$table`, so you tell it about the variable using `use`.

You can find it in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-168).

Comment: @Kame No problem, I had the same problem when I started learning PHP. :)

Answer (score 3):

Please try :

```
<?php 
$type = Input::get('type', null);
$table = $type . '_details';
$joinFunction = function($join) use ($table)
                {
                    $join->on($table . '.source_id', '=',  'links.source_id');
                    $join->on($table . '.brand_id','=', 'links.brand_id');
                }
$results =  \DB::table($table)
                ->join('links',$joinFunction )
                ->get();

?>
```

The problem was that the function doesn't see the $table variable inside it. That's why you need to use the "use" statement .

Read more about [anonymous functions in php here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)